# ЯндексКарт: Брать точки для "ломанной" из другого файла?

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Прошу помощи знающих людей. 
Дано: Есть данные по лыжным маршрутам. 
Реализовано: Обозначены маркерами начальный точки этих маршрутов, при клике на маркер открывается балун с изображением, описанием, и в консоль падает id этой точки.
Необходимо: 
При клике на маркер хочется, чтобы линия всего лыжного маршрута (еще порядка 200 точек на каждый маркер) начал анимацию.
Хранить такой объём точек в одном файле - не хочется. И для удобства дальнейшей работы, хочется, чтобы файл, откуда подгружается полный маршрут - лежал отдельно.

То есть, при клике на маркер с id=18 - JS должен обращаться к файлу dots18.json, брать оттуда все точки, и пихать их в переменную, чтобы я потом мог вызвать функцию .animate();

Спасибо за подсказки, в JS не так давно, только учусь.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример загрузки динамической загрузки дополнительных данных: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/om_balloon_ajax
Там же есть пример есть обработка события клика по метке.

Еще пример - загрузка GeoJSON файла из конструктора карт: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson

Или вот такой пример на коленке:

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {

  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.86, 37.71],
      zoom: 10,
      controls: ['zoomControl']
    }),
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.80899899270488, 37.77442932128906], {});
  map.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

  myPlacemark.events.add('click', function(e) {
    // Получим объект, на котором открылся балун.
    //var id = e.get('objectId'),
    //geoObject = objectManager.objects.getById(id);

    // Загружаем GeoJSON файл с описанием объектов.
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/12zwmc')
      .done(function(geoJson) {
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager(),
          // Добавляем описание объектов в формате JSON в менеджер объектов.
          objectManager.add(geoJson);
        // Добавляем объекты на карту.
        map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>Добавление на карту объектов</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    .map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://yastatic.net/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```